# To avoid typos how can I make MySql sql compiler check for table definitions when creating a new procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

Having the following DDL in MySql 5.5.x.

```
create table if not exists t1 (col1 int);
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc()
BEGIN
      select inexistent_column from t1;       
END;
```

Why the procedure is created without errors?
I expect it to throw that inexistent_column is not known or does not exists.
How can I make MySql sql compiler check for table definitions?

**UPDATE: Rephrase**

I just want a way to avoid a typo in a column while developing, meaning, creating a brand new procedure. Is there any way to do this? Maybe that should've been the question to ask from the start.

Comment: The procedure body is only parsed for syntax.  It is not evaluated until one calls the procedure.  Indeed, schema could change in between successive procedure calls: should MySQL drop existing procedures just because they reference a no-longer valid schema?

Comment: and as a follwup to eggyal, consider where a db is being reloaded from a dump. a sproc might be created that refers to a table/field that hasn't been reloaded yet. skipping the sproc because of that "error" would be bad, because that table/field WILL be loaded later as the dump gets processed.

Comment: Ok, both of you are correct. I just want a way to avoid a typo in a column while developing, meaning, creating a brand new procedure. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The server will only do syntax checking, but you can check for the existence of columns yourself. All existing tables and columns are defined in the `information_schema`.

You could use a query like this to check if your column exists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME   = 'your_table_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME  = 'some_column'
```

Comment: Or else just declare a handler for [`SQLSTATE '42S22'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_bad_field_error).